# Calculating percentage of polygon area that is greater than an elevation of a polygon from a diffrent layer in QGIS 3.14

Tags: qgis, elevation

Working with QGIS 3.14. I have a layer of 7000 Wetland Polygons each with a maximum elevation attribute. I also have a layer of watershed polygons that each of the 7000 polygons are within. I also have a DEM that covers the entire area I am interested in.

What I am trying to do is find out what percentage of each watershed is greater than the maximum elevation of the wetland. I am quite stuck on this.

Comment: split it in single tasks and solve it step by step